# Cannot use Dask to merge many CSV files (while Pandas works just fine)

Tags: python, pandas, dask

My use case is quite simple: read about 70k small CSV-gzipped files and merge them into a single zipped parquet file with a common index.
Every file weights about 3KB zipped, 9KB extracted. All the files zipped together are about 200MB in size.

The serial version looks like

```py
dfs = [ ]
for f in tqdm(files):
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    # do something simple to add a new index column
    dfs.append(df)

final = pd.concat(dfs)
# write final to disk as parquet file
```

This takes about 2 minutes, does not use a lot of memory and writes a file about 200MB in size, which is exactly what I expected.

I thought of optimizing the runtime using `Dask` so I constructed something similar

```py
with Client(n_workers=4) as client:
   df = dd.read_csv(files)
   # do the same thing to add a new column
   final = df.compute() # write it to disk afterwards
```

I had to stop this after 5 minutes of execution time because, after using a lot of Memory, dask started spilling stuff to disk in swap. And I was only at 5% of the entire progress!
Plus I get these warning continously

```
distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 34% CPU time recently
```

I would expect `Dask` to be advantaged in a similar task...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not an answer as I've not used dask, but - have you tried [polars](https://pypi.org/project/polars/)? `df = pl.scan_csv(f)` to lazy load, `df = df.with_columns(..)` to add column, `final = pl.concat()` to combine and `final.sink_parquet(filename)` to stream the result to disk.

Comment: @jqurious , please keep to the topic of the question, this is not a place to advertise alternatives the OP didn't ask for.

Answer (score 0):

An explanation of what the following code does

```
with Client(n_workers=4) as client:
   df = dd.read_csv(files)
   final = df.compute()
```

You are asking each worker, sharing your whole machine RAM, to process chunks of data, and then construct them into a single global dataframe in another procsee (the client process). This will involve a lot of seralization to send the pieces between processes and memory duplication in the process.

Dask will rarely give you a big boost, if any, for pure data load, which is often limited by your storage device. Also, you have chosen the distributed scheduler - please read about whether you really want this!

Dong .compute() so that you can write the results out is very much an anti-pattern, and is the main reason dask is slow. If the data all fit in one process, just use pandas. If you need to split into pieces for out-of-core and/or parallelism **do your write in the worker**. Any parallel/distributed system is like this (including polars' out-of-core - you cannot expect memory savings if the thing you do is immediately turn the data into an in-memory pandas dataframe).

This often means code like

```
with Client(n_workers=4) as client:
   df = dd.read_csv(files)
   df2 = df.assign(...) # and other processing
   df2.to_parquet(locaton)
```

Finally, you speak of setting an index, although this isn't shown. In dask, this is a special case which sorts your data, and can be very expensive ( https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.set_index.html ). Is that what you need?

Comment: Hey @mdurant, thanks for the answer. Let me comment on your suggestions.
- I did try to limit RAM usage per worker by using `memory_limit=0.1`, that didn't help
- I did try to write directly to a parquet file, without computing the file first, that showed the same behaviour
- About the index actually I'm not trying to setting it, because I know about the performance decrease. I just meant that I have a column used to distinguish the data coming from different files

Comment: To summarize: this task is embarassingly parallel in a way that I have to do the same operation many times on different files, combined them together and write to disk.
Pandas with a loop does 1 processing after the other keeping the result in memory: I could "parallelize" this by running multiple processes at the same time.
I wanted to use Dask in order to simplify this task, as I though it would optimize the loading of data into memory, and the subsequent merging and writing to disk. In a way, I  was just expecting for a better way of handling parallel loading and writing of small files.

Comment: But anyway, after testing I discovered that the real culprit is the `include_path_column` option. When I removed that I got the same performance of the serial case without any memory leak. That is still puzzling because I would expect the Dask version with 4 workers to be faster than the loop version, but as you said I think I'm hitting some overhead due to the distribution of load upon the workers.